# Discrete-time random process is Markov iif... (Proving a theorem)

Tags: markov-chains

First some background:

> > We say that $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a *Markov chain* with *initial distribution* $\lambda$ and *transition matrix* $P$ if (i) $X_0$ has distribution $\lambda$; (ii) for $n\geq 0$, conditional on $X_n=i$, $X_{n+1}$ has distribution $(p_{ij}: j\in I)$ and is independent of $X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1}$. More explicitly, these conditions state that, for $n\geq 0$, and $i_0,\ldots,i_{n+1}\in I$, (i) $\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0)=\lambda_{i_0}$, (ii) $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_n=i_n)=p_{i_n i_{n+1}}$. We say that $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is *Markov*($\lambda,P$) for short.

Now the following Theorem is shown:

> > A discrete-time random process $(X_n)_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is Markov($\lambda,P$) iff for all $i_0,\ldots,i_N\in I$
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,X_1=i_1,\ldots,X_N=i_N)=\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}p_{i_1i_2}\ldots p_{i_{N-1}i_N}.~~~~~~~(*)
> > $$

Now the **proof** is given. I do understand the first direction:

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose $(X_n)_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is Markov($\lambda,P$). Then one can write
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,X_1=i_1,\ldots,X_N=i_N)\\=\mathbb{P}(X_N=i_N|X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_{N-1}=i_{N-1})\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_{N-1}=i_{N-1})\\=p_{i_{N-1}i_N}\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_{N-1}=i_{N-1}|X_0=i_0,\ldots X_{N-2}=i_{N-2})\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_{N-2}=i_{N-2})\\=\ldots\\=p_{i_{N-1}i_N}\ldots\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0)\mathbb{P}(X_1=i_1|X_0=i_0)\\=\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}\ldots p_{i_{N-1}i_N}
$$

But I do not understand the other direction. I cite it:

> > On the other hand, if $(*)$ holds for $N$, then by summing both sides over $i_N\in I$ and using $\sum_{j\in I}p_{ij}=1$ we see that $(*)$ holds for $N-1$ and, by induction
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=i_n)=\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}\ldots p_{i_{n-1}i_n}
> > $$
> >     for all $n=0,\cdots,N$. In particular, $\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0)=\lambda_{i_0}$ and, for $n=1,1,\cdots,N-1$,
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_n=i_n)\\=\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_n=i_n,X_{n+1}=i_{n+1})/\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_n=i_n)\\=p_{i_ni_{n+1}}.
> > $$
> >     So $(X_n)_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is Markov($\lambda,P$).

---

Could you please explain me the proof of direction $\Leftarrow$?

I do not understand f.e. what is meant by

> > [...] if $(*)$ holds for $N$, then by summing both sides over $i_N\in I$ and using $\sum_{j\in I}p_{ij}=1$ we see that $(*)$ holds for $N-1$ and, by induction [...]

**Edit 1:** I think this means
$$
\sum_{i_N\in I}\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_N=i_N)=\sum_{i_N\in I}\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}\ldots p_{i_{N-1}i_N}\\=\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}\ldots p_{i_{N-2}i_{N-1}}\underbrace{\sum_{i_N\in I}p_{i_{N-1}i_N}}_{=1}\\=\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}\ldots p_{i_{N-2}i_{N-1}}
$$

But why does this show that $(*)$ holds for $N-1$? Cannot see that.

**Edit 2:** I think this is because of the law of total probability, i.e. summing over $i_N\in I$ gives on LHS
$$
\sum_{i_N\in I}\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_N=i_N)=\sum_{i_N\in I}\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_{N-1}=i_{N-1}|X_N=i_N)\mathbb{P}(X_N=i_N)\\=\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_{N-1}=i_{N-1})
$$
and on RHS (as ritten above) $\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}\ldots p_{i_{N-2}i_{N-1}}$, so we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_{N-1}=i_{N-1})=\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}\ldots p_{i_{N-2}i_{N-1}}.
$$
Now with the same reasoning one can show that $(*)$ holds for $n=0,\ldots,N-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$P(X_0=i_0,X_1=i_1,...,X_N=i_N)=\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}p_{i_1i_2}...p_{i_{N-1}i_{N}}$$ hold true for all $N$.
Then it must be true that
$$P(X_0=i_0,X_1=i_1,...,X_{N-1}=i_{N-1})=\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}p_{i_1i_2}...p_{i_{N-2}i_{N-1}}$$
But $$P(X_N=i_N|X_0=i_0,...,X_{N-1}=i_{N-1})=\frac{P(X_0=i_0,X_1=i_1,...,X_N=i_N)}{P(X_0=i_0,X_1=i_1,...,X_{N-1}=i_{N-1})}=\frac{\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}p_{i_1i_2}...p_{i_{N-1}i_{N}}}{\lambda_{i_0}p_{i_0i_1}p_{i_1i_2}...p_{i_{N-2}i_{N-1}}}=p_{i_{N-1}i_N}$$
for all $N$. And this is what Markov chain is.

Comment: I added an idea. I think this has to do with the law of total probability, right? Please see my last edit.

Comment: @math12: True your idea helps actually prove point $i$. But for $ii$ I think you have to use my suggestion above.

Comment: I think one can use that $(*)$ holds for $n=0,1,..., N-1$ by the argument above in my post to show now (ii).